# Call a function from a "html table" in drupal 7

Tags: php, module, drupal-7

I need to call the FUNCTION when the BUTTON is clicked. How I can do this?
(I know that the code I wrote is wrong, it's just to make it clear)

```
function gh_view_categories(){
  $a='<table>';
  $a.='<tr>';
  $a.='<td><strong>'.'Categoria:'.'</strong></td>';
  $a.='<td><strong>'.'Soglia minima:'.'</strong></td>';
  $a.='<td><strong>'.'Tot attuale:'.'</strong></td>';
  $a.='<td><strong>'.'Crea ordine'.'</strong></td>';
  $a.='</tr>';
  $query = db_select('uc_product_classes', 'u')
    ->fields('u', array('name','soglia', 'totattuale'));
  $result = $query->execute();
  while ($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    $idUser=gh_get_user_id($record['name']);
    $a.='<tr>';
    $a.='<td>'.$record['name'].'</td>';
    $a.='<td>'.$record['soglia'].'</td>';
    $a.='<td>'.$record['totattuale'].'</td>';
    $a.='<td>'.l('BUTTON', FUNCTION($idUser)')).'</td>';
    $a.='</tr>';
  }

  $a.='</table>';
  return $a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in your html button tag:

```html
<button onClick="yourFunction()">
```

Comment: Thanks, i've add this code, the button appear but it not works.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't, do you get any errors in the console?
and is the name of the function right?
is your function right without errors?

Comment: the button is clickable but nothing happens. I tried a very simple function uc_cart_prova function () {
   echo ('OK');
   return ('OK');
}

Comment: Well I need to see all the code before I can help you further